# Updated iOS Application uses Notification Settings from old Application

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification

I recently updated my iOS application version 1.0 to version 2.0 and Push Notifications don't work as expected.

In version 1.0 I asked the user to allow notifications for the type `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` which I needed to set the application icons badge value. However, I only set the badge value locally, so no remote notifications where involved.

In version 2.0 I now want to use remote notifications to notify the user about certain events. Thus, in the AppDelegate I register all the available types of `UIUserNotificationSettings`:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
    }
```

The issue I am facing now in version 2.0 is that the notificationSettings I am getting in the delegate `-(void)application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` are set to the old settings from app version 1.0. (I only get `UIUserNotificationsTypeBadge`)

Also there won't be any prompt in version 2.0 asking the user for notification permissions. And the very strange thing is that in the settings the notification style banner is selected. (see picture below)

I also figured out that toggling notifications on and off for the app kind of overrides the settings from the old app and I get the expected user notifications settings in `-(void)application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` --> `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound`

[image: Notification Settings of the app]

Is anyone facing the same issue and found a solution how to programmatically override the old notifications settings without having to manually toggle notifications on and off in the settings?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!